# How to troubleshoot "Unexpected token, expected ; (44:33)" in React Native using ES6 syntax

Tags: ios, syntax, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm working on building a simple bingo game to get chores completed on iOS and Android using React-Native. I'm new to JS with experience in Java and Python in the past so my bias was towards using the ES6 syntax which has some familiar constructs to the aforementioned languages.

I am running into a syntax error which I'm not able to identify in the file that I'm pasting in here (this is the full code of that file). The error I'm getting from the iOS emulator for this file is:

> Unexpected token, expected ; (44:33)

Just to make it easier to tie into what line 44 is (I believe (44:33) means line 44 character 33) I'm seeing line 44 as the following in Atom.

```
_createPlayerTabs(playerCount) {
```

I have done as much research on Google, the Facebook React Native site, and here as possible but it's been very difficult since google doesn't recognize semicolons as a legitimate search token :(. I suspect I'm making some sort of error based on assuming that JS functions like Python or Java but any help you guys could provide on what the specific error is or what conceptual mistake I'm making would be greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Picker,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import {
  TabViewAnimated,
  TabBarTop,
} from 'react-native-tab-view';

import GlobalStyles from '../../styles/GlobalStyles';
import BingoBoard from '../../components/BingoBoard';

class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      routes: this._createPlayerTabs(this.props.players),
    };
  }

  _setupPlayers(playerCount, boardSize, winCondition) {
    players = []
    for (var x = 1; x <= playerCount; x++) {
      tempBoard = new BingoBoard(boardSize, winCondition);
      players.push('Player '.concat(x.toString()) : {
        name: "",
        board: tempBoard,
      });
  }

  _createPlayerTabs(playerCount) {
    playerList = [];
    for (var x = 1; x <= playerCount; x++) {
      playerList.push({
        key: x.toString(),
        title: "Player ".concat(x.toString()),
      });
    }
    return playerList;
  }

  _renderScene({ route }) {
    return
      <View style={[GlobalStyles.container, {paddingTop: 500}]}>
        <Text>
          {route.title}
        </Text>
      </View>;
  }

  _renderHeader(props) {
    return <TabBarTop {...props} />;
  }

  _handleChangeTab = (index) => {
    this.setState({ index });
  }

  render() {
     return(
       <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
         <TabViewAnimated
           style={GlobalStyles.container}
           navigationState={this.state}
           renderScene={this._renderScene}
           renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
           onRequestChangeTab={this._handleChangeTab}/>
         <View style={GlobalStyles.bottomBar}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => (
                   Actions.activechore({this.state.players})
               )}>
               <Text style={GlobalStyles.h2}>
                 Next
               </Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
       </View>
     );
  }
}

export default Player;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in `_setupPlayers` is missing its closing `}`, so it's trying to parse `_createPlayerTabs(playerCount) {` as a statement, and failing.